# count number of elements with a specific value in a field of a structure in Matlab

Tags: matlab, count, structure, field

I have a structure *myS* with several fields, including *myField*, which in turns includes several other fields such as *BB*. I need to count how many time *'R_value' appears in *BB*.

I have tried:
`sum(myS.myField.BB = 'R_value')`

and this:

```
count = 0;
for i = 1:numel(myS.myField)
    number_of_element = numel(myS.myField(i).BB)=='R_value'
    count = count+number_of_element;
end
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Comment: is `'R_value'` pseudocode, or is it really the string  literal `'R_value'` that you are looking for?

Comment: `'R_value'` is a string.

Comment: And what is `BB` then, just a string? Then why are you using `numel` and counting the number of elements, if its either 1 or 0? thats an `if`

Answer (score 1):

If you are just checking if `BB` is that literal string, then your loop is just:

```
count = 0;
for i = 1:numel(myS.myField)
    count = count+strcmp(myS.myField(i).BB,'R_value') 
end
```

---

`numel` counts how many elements are. Zero is an element. so is False. Just sum the array.

```
count = 0;
for i = 1:numel(myS.myField)
    number_of_element = sum(myS.myField(i).BB==R_value) 
    count = count+number_of_element;
end
```

Also note you had the parenthesis wrong, so you where counting how many `BB` where in total, then comparing that number to `R_value`. I am assuming `R_value` is a number.

e.g.:

```
myS.myField(1).BB=[1 2 3 4 1 1 1]
myS.myField(2).BB=[4 5 65 1]
R_value=1
```